# Ellipse Stroke background color

Tags: c#, wpf, stroke

I have an ellipse with a stroke, so:

```
myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
```

I need it to be yellow, but it doesn't always show up nicely on white backgrounds, which is pretty common in this scenario.

I was wondering if there was a way to put the Yellow Stroke on a black background.

```
myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
myEllipse.Stroke = Brushes.Yellow;
```

Where instead of the yellow replacing the black, it would be a combination so that it always appears yellow as if the background image was black.

Comment: No,  but you can overlay two ellipses with a different `StrokeThickness`. Another possiblity would be to calculate a `RadialGradientBrush` that fits your needs, but that would be a lot more effort.

Comment: This problem is very common, look at your mouse pointer. It has to be visible disregards background color. And most obvious solution is to use outlining, when there is a thin contour around the object drawn in opposite (inverted?) color. To actually draw that contour the simplest technique is to draw first slightly increased object (using same center point) with inverted color and then draw original one on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could draw two ellipses on top of each other. The first would be black and slightly thicker than the second which would be yellow.

They get drawn in the order they are added to their container object (view, grid or whatever), so make sure you add them in the order "black" then "yellow".